UART Connector - Any open standard like STEMMA / quiic?
I'm adding a debug connector in my new design. I am looking for a connector standard for UART debug pins. I found this RaspberryPi 3-pin debug connector as a standard, but it does not have the VCC / power pin. (I'm also planning to make an isolated UART debug probe which needs the VCC pin to sense the logic level.)
There is the STEMMA connector but the UART pinout standard is not defined for it. Then there is the Grove UART connector which seems like a suitable option, but the connector part is a proprietary one, so I'm avoiding that one.
Is there an open UART debug connector standard like Sparkfun's quiic / Adafruit's STEMMA (which all use JST SH / PH connectors)?

Just by curiosity, are you looking for open standards to avoid royalties and/or certification costs? I know USB has royalties but I didn't know UART was that case.

No, but feel free to use any pinout and connector you want by expanding on the Raspberry Pi standard.
The closest thing could be Digilent PMOD but it's technically not a connector but just a pin header.
Basically take any USB-UART adapter with pinheader connector for VCC, GND, TXD and RXD as a reference. Some provide individually crimped connectors on each so they fit into any pinout.
Having a standard for this would require someone to come up with a connector, pinout, need to supply Vtarget for level shifting, and be intended for some purpose.
Most people just invent their own "standard" based on what they need or what their previous board had so they don't have to invent a new one.

Thanks for sharing your insights, it makes sense.
Digilent PMOD is new for me. But I think I will expand the Raspberry Pi standard for now, like you suggested :)

I use so called "Raspberry Pi 3.3V TTL" cables almost daily. It does not matter if a board was designed by me or by a customer, as long as there's a 0.1" pin header with TX, RX and GND in some order I can connect to for debugging. The plus side is, no need to design anything or define a standard beyond that. Once I used a flat flex connector for bringing JTAG and UART to a breakout board. The downside is, you always need that breakout board, your customer needs one too, you need to tell how to wire it, the pinout is usually wrong because of flat flexes flipping or passing the pinout.
